What are these to status bar icons

What are these two status bar icons?

The first is Facebook Messenger's. Never seen the other. Anyway, it should match on of your installed apps.

Sorry, we don't do app notification icon identification anymore because it's just infeasible with millions of Android apps, including non-public apps, and rarely helps future users.
